# Access an element when the "Submit" button is clicked to get the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, api

So here's a great example from https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2

What I want to do and trying is this:

I have a simply webpage whereby I want to display the current forecast and extended forecast.

Here's my Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title>Weather Forecaster</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Oxygen-Icons.org-Oxygen-Status-weather-clear.ico" />
        <!-- END favicon -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/jquery.jdigiclock.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/wx-custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="wxController as ctrlWx">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-10">
                    <div id="my-div" ng-model="myiFrame">
                        <iframe src="http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html" id="my-iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div id="plugin_container" class="forecast-panel">
                        <h1>Here's Today's Weather</h1>
                        <div class="fc forecast-panel1">
                            <p class="dayTitle">Day 1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                        <div class="fc forecast-panel2">
                            <p class="dayTitle">Day 2</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                        <div class="fc forecast-panel3">
                            <p class="dayTitle">Day 3</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                        <div class="fc forecast-panel4">
                            <p class="dayTitle">Day 4</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacer"></div>
                        <div class="fc forecast-panel5">
                            <p class="dayTitle">Day 5</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/angular/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/angular/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/angular/services.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/angular/ang-custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice the "IFRAME".... the src is this: http://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html

Now, if you go there, which is pretty cool, you can put ANY address to get the LAT LON for that address:

Here's a screen shot with an example LAT LON from DC... the Whitehouse.

[image: Example of my project]

OK, now, my code uses Angular with a simple controller and service...

Here:

APP:

```
/* global angular */
// Code goes here
var myApp;
myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', '**']);
});
console.log("Host name is: " + document.location.hostname);
//if (document.location.hostname === "localhost") {
//    myApp.constant('URL', '/WeatherForecaster/js/json/');
//} else if (document.location.hostname === "omnimanger.co/wx" || "www.omnimanager.co/wx") {
//    myApp.constant('URL', '/js/json/');
//} else {
//    myApp.constant('URL', '/wx/js/json/');
//}
myApp.constant("URL", {
   //Default LAT/LON for CONCRETE 
   apiKey: "3bb0f0fe93c92922f0b42f9eabda48d0/",
   lat: "48.530031",
   lon: ",-121.879460",
   country: "us",
   uri: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"
}).config(function($httpProvider){
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});;

myApp.constant("wx", {
    data: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        currently: {},
        minutely: {
            summary: "",
            icon: "",
            data: []
        },
        hourly: {
            summary: "",
            icon: "",
            data: []
        },
        daily: {
            summary: "",
            icon: "",
            data: []
        },
        flags: {
            sources: [],
            "lamp-stations": [],
            "isd-stations": [],
            "madis-stations": [],
            units: ""
        }
    }
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
'use strict';
myApp.controller('wxController', function (wxDataService) {

    var ctrlWx = this;
    //Listen for the Submit (FIND) button on the iFrame

    ctrlWx.content = {};
    console.log("LAT/LON: ", ctrlWx.latlon);
    ctrlWx.fetchWx = function () {
        //General Data
        wxDataService.getWxData().then(function (result) {
            ctrlWx.content = result;
            console.log("All Data: ", result);
        });
    };
    ctrlWx.fetchWx();

});
```

SERVICE:

```
myApp.factory('wxDataService', function ($http, URL) {

    console.log("URL", URL);

        //DEFAULT Headers for KEY and AUTH TOKEN
    var headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': ['GET', 'POST'],
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    var myURL = {
        data: {
            header: headers,
            uri: URL.uri + URL.apiKey + URL.lat + URL.lon
        }
    };

    var getWxData = function () {
        return $http.get(myURL)
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS!");
                    console.log("The Weather Data is here: " + data);
                    return data;
                })
                .error(function (e) {
                    console.log("He\'s dead Jim!<br>", e);
                    return e;
                });
    };
    return {
        getWxData: getWxData
    };
});
```

SOLUTION I'm Trying to Achieve:

When the user enters the address and clicks the "FIND" button, which generates the LAT LON, I want to capture that LAT LON inside the IFRAME.

This is what I'm trying to do, but I know I need to make a directive that BINDS the "CLICK" or "SUBMIT" event to the FIND button.  What I have below is NOT that; yet.

```
var latlon = {};
$(function () {
    $('#my-iframe').load(function () {

        $(this).contents().find("#latlongform, #gadres").live('blur', function (e) {
            latlon = {
                mylat: $("input[name='lat']").val(),
                mylon: $("input[name='lon']").val()
            };
            if (e) {
                console.log("Err: ", e);
                return e;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

GIVENS:

The FORM and the LAT LON are as follows:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 graybox">
            <form id="latlongform">
                <label for="gadres">Address</label>
                <input id="gadres" type="text" class="width70" placeholder="Type address here to get lat long" required="">
                <button title="Find lat long coordinates" class="button">Find</button><br>
                <small>Write city name with country code for better results.</small>
            </form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 m2">
                    <label for="lat">Latitude</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" placeholder="lat coordinate">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 m2">
                    <label for="lng">Longitude</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" placeholder="long coordinate">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

QUESTION:

How can I get the LAT LON, "AFTER" the user clicks FIND, THEN fire my angular service to inject the CALL to the URL which gets the WEATHER DATA...as described. Here's that WEATHER DATA JSON OBJECT.  It uses an API KEY which mine is limited to 1000 uses per day.

If you'd like to see what the result is on the weather API, you need to get a FREE API_KEY.... it gives 1000 hits per day...

Thanks everyone and I hope you can all this this is a VALID question.

Comment: You can't access inside a cross domain iframe due to ***same origin policy***. Also note that `live()` has been deprecated for many years. In addition does no good trying to set CORS Access-control headers on client side requests. They must be set by server in response

Comment: Live() - yes, I mistyped... forgive me.  So there's absolutely no way to get that data then?  If not, I'll simply have my own form or do you know of another way to do what that example is doing?  Thanks Charlie... I appreciate your kind assistance.

Comment: Use AJAX do get the data from the weather API from your own form, is the way APIs are meant to be used.

Comment: Right, use own form. Can geocode through any service

Comment: I thought so and want to but I was trying to find a "cool" way to integrate something that already existed.  No worries, Charlie.  Can I give you and Franco a "thumbs up" for both your combined answers? Sorry for the stupid question.  Forgive me gentlemen.

Answer (score 1):

### Accessing the Forecast.io API with JSONP

The `forecast.io` website doesn't support CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) for GET operations but it does support JSONP.

### Revised Code

```
var url = myURL.data.uri;
var jsonpURL = url+"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

var getWxData = function () {
    return $http.jsonp(jsonpURL)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("SUCCESS!");
            console.log(response.data);
            //return to chain data
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log("He\'s dead Jim!");
            console.log(e);
            //throw to chain rejection
            throw e;
        });
};
```

### Sample Result

```
LAT: 48.530031
LOG: -121.87946
TIMEZONE: America/Los_Angeles
SUMMARY: Partly Cloudy
TEMP: 56.02
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sswhs6vc/).

Notice that I changed the `.success` and `.error` methods to `.then` and `.catch` respectively. Those old methods are [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) and **ignore** return values.